# What is the difference between the electrode:component and electrode-component archetypes?

Tags: walmart-electrode

The main [doc](http://www.electrode.io/docs/what_is_electrode.html) suggests `electrode:component` but, this [doc](https://github.com/electrode-io/electrode/tree/master/packages/electrode-archetype-react-component) suggests `electrode-component`?

Answer (score 0):

Electrode comes with yeoman generator to quickly create a shell for your component.

The command to invoke the component generator is:

`yo electrode:component`

`electrode-component` is just a suggested name for the component you would generate.